# Combining rows of data in R; summing a column by other columns

Tags: r

This is the current structure of my data:

| Area | Item | Element | Year1 | Year2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Africa | Enteric | CH4 | 2 | 3 |
| Africa | Enteric | C02 | 1.5 | 2 |
| Africa | Manure | CH4 | 3 | 1 |
| Africa | Manure | CO2 | 0.5 | 2 |
| Europe | Enteric | CH4 | 2.5 | 2 |
| Europe | Enteric | C02 | 1.7 | 2.3 |
| Europe | Manure | CH4 | 3 | 4 |
| Europe | Manure | CO2 | 1.5 | 1.5 |

I however want to sum "Years" by "Area" and "Item" such that my new that structure is like below:

| Area | Item | Year1 | Year2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Africa | Enteric | 3.5 | 5 |
| Africa | Manure | 3.5 | 3 |
| Europe | Enteric | 4.2 | 4.3 |
| Europe | Manure | 4.5 | 5.5 |

Comment: I presume you meant "Year1" and "Year2" not "Element".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dplyr` solution. This is one of the most basic use case of `group_by` and `summarise`

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "Area   Item    Element Year1   Year2
Africa  Enteric CH4 2   3
Africa  Enteric C02 1.5 2
Africa  Manure  CH4 3   1
Africa  Manure  CO2 0.5 2
Europe  Enteric CH4 2.5 2
Europe  Enteric C02 1.7 2.3
Europe  Manure  CH4 3   4
Europe  Manure  CO2 1.5 1.5", header = T) %>% 
  as_tibble()

df %>% 
  group_by(Area, Item) %>% 
  summarise(Year1 = sum(Year1),
            Year2 = sum(Year2))
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'Area' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#> # Groups:   Area [2]
#>   Area   Item    Year1 Year2
#>   <chr>  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Africa Enteric   3.5   5  
#> 2 Africa Manure    3.5   3  
#> 3 Europe Enteric   4.2   4.3
#> 4 Europe Manure    4.5   5.5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I guess `aggregate` from base R could help

```
> aggregate(cbind(Year1, Year2) ~ Area + Item, df, sum)
    Area    Item Year1 Year2
1 Africa Enteric   3.5   5.0
2 Europe Enteric   4.2   4.3
3 Africa  Manure   3.5   3.0
4 Europe  Manure   4.5   5.5
```

**data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Area = c("Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe"), Item = c("Enteric",
"Enteric", "Manure", "Manure", "Enteric", "Enteric", "Manure",
"Manure"), Element = c("CH4", "C02", "CH4", "CO2", "CH4", "C02",
"CH4", "CO2"), Year1 = c(2, 1.5, 3, 0.5, 2.5, 1.7, 3, 1.5), Year2 = c(3,
2, 1, 2, 2, 2.3, 4, 1.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-8L))
```